# How to determine if string is keyof interface in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, deserialization

I am trying to transform a CSS string into a `React.CSSProperties` object, but am getting a typing error with a Typescript upgrade to 3.5.3.

TLDR; how to map strings to properties allowed by an interface

```
export function styleStringToCSSProperties(style: string | null) {
   const out: React.CSSProperties = {};

   if (!style) return null;

   const properties = style.split(';');
   if (!properties.length) return null;

   for (const property of properties) {
       const [key, value] = property.split(':');

       // Error here because I'm assuming the type checker sees the 
       // 'string' type output of 'camelCase' and because any string
       // is not limited to the exact possibilities in the error msg
       // below.  I was thinking of checking if the value of the output
       // of 'camelCase' is one of the allowed interface keys, but I 
       // can't find a way to do that


      // `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"-moz-initial" | 
      // "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | undefined'`

       out[camelCase(key) as keyof React.CSSProperties] = value;

       // ^^^^ Brorked
  }

 return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the value you are trying to assign isn't equal to one of the allowed values `"-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | undefined`

**Edit**

It could also be caused by type checking. I just noticed your value comes from a string split. Which means it's also a string.

That means that you have a string on one side, and a set number of allowed values on the other. Typescript isn't going to like it.

You could try to coerce your string type doing something like

```
out[camelCase(key) as keyof React.CSSProperties] = value as typeof (out[camelCase(key) as keyof React.CSSProperties]);
```

worst case scenario you can convert your value to an `any`

```
out[camelCase(key) as keyof React.CSSProperties] = value as any;
```

But I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: It's not the `value` its the `key` (sorry I should have specified that better)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just forcing it and ignoring the typescript error :-/